# Pandas create column by using either of two columns chosen on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a DataFrame in Pandas:

```
name    type    A   B       C           
n1      t1      1   32      3
n2      t1      52  2437    3
n3      t2      21  0       100
n4      t1      53  2005    2   
n5      t2      34  1       200
```

What I want to create is another DataFrame by adding another column obtained through manipulation of columns `A`, `B` and `C`.
Specifically, I want that when type is `t1`, the column would be calculated as `A/C`; when type is `t2` the column would be calculated as `B/C` instead.

How to achieve this conditional creation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df['new'] = np.where(df['type'].isin(['t1']), df.A/df.C, df.B/df.C )
print df
  name type   A     B    C        new
0   n1   t1   1    32    3   0.333333
1   n2   t1  52  2437    3  17.333333
2   n3   t2  21     0  100   0.000000
3   n4   t1  53  2005    2  26.500000
4   n5   t2  34     1  200   0.005000
```

Or better and safer [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df.loc[df['type'].isin(['t1']), 'new'] = df.A / df.C
df.loc[df['type'].isin(['t2']), 'new'] = df.B / df.C
print df
  name type   A     B    C        new
0   n1   t1   1    32    3   0.333333
1   n2   t1  52  2437    3  17.333333
2   n3   t2  21     0  100   0.000000
3   n4   t1  53  2005    2  26.500000
4   n5   t2  34     1  200   0.005000
```

Comment: @ jezrael First one (np.where) is if there are only two types in `type` column?